# Error in executing the mondod service Permission denied: "/mongo/data/mongod.lock

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to run the mongo service with the non-standard dbpath parameter of mongodb, I'm not using '/var/lib/mongo', but instead it's set to '/mongo/data'.

The reason for this change is to apply encryption protection in the base directory and in this default directory '/var/lib/' the cryptographic system does not allow it.

Even giving 'sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /mongo/data' permissions on the directory, when running the service it returns the error of permission denied.

Versions:
CentOS Linux 7.9.2009
MongoDB 6.0.3

`**`Follow permissions:
`**[root@localhost /]#` ls -l /mongo/data
total 248
-rw-------. 1 mongod mongod     0 Jan 20 12:21 mongod.lock

`**Follow the error logs:**
"attr":{"error":"Location28596: Unable to determine status of lock file in the data directory /mongo/data: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/mongo/data/mongod.lock""}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-20T14:24:38.268-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}**

```
Can you please help me with this error?

I tried to give all the necessary read and write permissions on the directory, but without success.
```

Comment: Is selinux enforcing on your system?

Comment: Do you start the mongo service as user mongod? Check permissions of the lock file. Perhaps it was left at an earlier crash.

Comment: I am starting the service through the command:
sudo systemctl start mongod

Follow the permissions lock file:
ls -l /mongo/data total 248 -rw-------. 1 mongod mongod 0 Jan 20 12:21 mongod.lock

Comment: @Joe, yes the selinux enforcing it is enable in the system.

Comment: After changing the permissions of the new database path I was still having this issue, I ran getenforce to see if I'm using a system with SELinux mode. imposition. And getenforce returned 'enforcing', it was likely that selinux was the cause of the permission error as mongod was now running outside its original context scope as the database location changed from /var/lib/..  I found the way to solve it in my test environment, but a brute force way to solve the problem without writing your own selinux policy for the new context is to simply shut down selinux :-/
sudo setenforce 0

Comment: Thank you all, I managed to solve the problem with your help! Joe and Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: you might also check out https://serverfault.com/questions/770227/selinux-setup-for-mongodb